# WMTS displaying emty tiles in leaflet js

Tags: javascript, api, leaflet, maps, wms

I'm using leaflet js and lantmateriet api for displaying map. But the map displaying empty white tiles in the browser. Map displaying fine with other api's like OSM. Im getting problem with lantmateriet api. This is my code.

```js
var mapOptions = {
  center: [59.4022, 13.5115],
  zoom: 4
}

var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions);
L.tileLayer('https://api.lantmateriet.se/open/topowebb-ccby/v1/wmts/token/apikey/1.0.0/topowebb/default/3006/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
  attribution: ''
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([59.3293, 18.0686]).addTo(map);
var m2 = L.marker([59.9139, 10.7522]).addTo(map);
m2.bindPopup("Oslo").addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup('Stockholm').addTo(map);

var latlngs = [
  [59.9139, 10.7522],
  [59.4022, 13.5115],
  [59.3293, 18.0686]
];
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {
  color: 'red'
});
polyline.addTo(map);

var circleCenter = [59.4022, 13.5115]; // Center of the circle
var circleOptions = {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5,
}
// Creating a circle
var circle = L.circle(circleCenter, 10000, circleOptions);
circle.addTo(map); // Adding circle to the map
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Leaflet sample</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 580px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet fully functional ?

Comment: @SébastienBousquet, I have updated the snippet. This is the code im using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with authentication to lantmateriet (all requests get a 401 return code), I didn't see anywhere a token for authentication.

I think you have to check that first.

[image: 401 unauthorized]

Comment: Hi @sebastien. Thank you for your answer. But we need to change the apikey in the url. I have removed my apikey for security reasons  form the URL while posting in the question.

Comment: Can you create a temporary Key because help you about tiles display without  this, it's complicated